# Apache answers request it shouldn't

Tags: virtualhost, redirect, apache-2.2

I have the following 2 domain records

```
website.com 10.0.0.1
www.website.com 10.0.0.1
```

I have(had) the following 2 Virtualhosts

```
#note how the IP address is wrong
<VirtualHost 10.0.0.2:80>

    ServerName website.com
    Redirect / http://www.website.com

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 10.0.0.1:80>

    ServerName www.website.com
  #note how there is no alias here
    DocumentRoot /var/www/www.website.com

    <IfModule mpm_itk_module>
            AssignUserId www-website www-website
    </IfModule>

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/www.website.com-access.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/www.website.com-error.log

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 10.0.0.1:443>
    ServerName www.website.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/www.website.com

    <IfModule mpm_itk_module>
            AssignUserId www-website www-website
    </IfModule>

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/www.website.com

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/www.website.com-ssl-access.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/www.website.com-ssl-error.log

</VirtualHost>
```

I expected that a request to http://website.com would be returned with a 404. However it was served as if it was delivered from http://www.website.com. Why?

Comment: The very first declared virtual host will act as catch-all if domain name is unknown. _"it was served as if it was delivered from http://www.website.com"_ -- did you saw redirect .. or it was served without redirect. If there was no redirect then your 2nd virtual host was "the very first" for that IP. That is my understanding of the situation (but who knows -- maybe I am wrong here).

Comment: You are right, but we have many more virtual hosts on that server including that "first one", which is completely different

Comment: In my experience, Apache will pick one at random to act as the catch-all. I know various places say you can specify it, or the first one will be it, but that doesn't seem as reliable as I'd like.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler First to load - I've depended heavily on this behavior ;) See [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html); "If no matching virtual host is found, then the first listed virtual host that matches the IP address will be used."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LazyOne is exactly right. As long as you have your `NameVirtualHost` directives sorted out, then the first `VirtualHost` defined for the **ip address** requested is used, if no other `ServerName` or `ServerAlias` matches exist.

Therefore, if you want to serve a 404 for each ip address that doesn't hit a host header match, create a `VirtualHost` (per ip) without a `ServerName` or `ServerAlias` directive, and position it in the config so that it is loaded first. Something like:

```
<VirtualHost 10.0.0.1:80>
    Redirect 404 /   
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 10.0.0.2:80>
    Redirect 404 /   
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 10.0.0.2:80>
    ServerName website.com
    Redirect / http://www.website.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 10.0.0.1:80>
    ServerName www.website.com
    #note how there is no alias here
    DocumentRoot /var/www/www.website.com
...
</VirtualHost>
```

**Update**: Most of the following is cribbed from the apache2 docs, [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/configuring.html) and [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#include).

The main config file, generally named httpd.conf, is loaded first. But if you're using a binary package on a debian-based system, there's a good chance it'll be called apache2.conf. Other config files are added using the `Include` directive in the main config. Multiple uses of the `Include` directive are allowed. `Include` directives may use fnmatch-style wildcards to load several config files at once, in **alphabetical order**.

To clarify further (hopefully), your main config is loaded first. As `Include` directives are encountered, they are loaded in the order they appear in the main config. If an individual `Include` uses a wildcard, each config file that matches is loaded in alphabetical order.

On a debian server, apache2.conf may look something like this:

```
# Include module configuration:
# ...
Include mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include all the user configurations:
Include httpd.conf

# Include ports listing
Include ports.conf

# ...

# Include generic snippets of statements
Include conf.d/

# Include the virtual host configurations:
Include sites-enabled/
```

In other words, any file ending in `.conf` in mods-enabled/ is loaded before httpd.conf, which is loaded before ports.conf, which is loaded before any file in conf.d/, etc.

Comment: Dead on.  To add to this; @jdog, your second `VirtualHost` is catching the request because the host file points that domain name to `10.0.0.1`, while the `VirtualHost` handling the redirect is on `10.0.0.2`; therefore, the first vhost to load on `10.0.0.1:80` handles the request.

Comment: Upvote for stealing an answer from the comments section! You win one half of an internet. http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1886/how-to-handle-unanswered-questions-that-have-the-answer-in-a-comment-or-edited-in

Comment: ok, so if they are all in separate files, what order is taken?

Comment: @jdog Still first to load.  Say, for instance, if your main apache config is including a directory full of files that each contain a `VirtualHost`, they're loaded alphabetically, so the first one alphabetically will be the default for that IP:port combination.

Comment: @shane you put me to shame with your succinctness :)

Comment: @wesley I'll be happy to take payment of one additional half of an internet please, at your convenience, thank you very much. I promise to keep only one eighth and donate the remainder to a good cause.

Comment: @Marty Oops - wasn't trying to show you up or anything, didn't see your edit before my comment.  Good answer :)

Comment: @shane, thanks, great answer, I thought the same, but I forgot " for that IP:port combination"